# Calculate Field Tool in ArcMap to add objectid to a string

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, oracle-dbms, error-999999

The table is in an Oracle Enterprise Geodatabase. As for the language processor I am unsure.

In an ArcMap table I am trying to use the Field Calculator to place the objectid with a string of text.

Ex. `"urn:emergency:uid:gis:SSAP:" + [OBJECTID] + ":" + [DISCRPAGID]`
DISCRPAGID is text.

Gives me an generic 999999 error.

the string should result in as urn:emergency:uid:gis:SSAP:507269:orangecountyfl.net
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You haven't stated what the format of the data source is, or what language processor you are using.  Generally you'd need to use the syntax appropriate to the parser. Please [Edit] the Question

Comment: Thank you Vince. I have added the information that I know.

Comment: Calculate Field has a pick-list on the processor options -- VBA or several flavors of Python. You need to tell us which one. Generally speaking, string math is bad, especially in Python.

Comment: Did you try to write in a text field with enough length ? if you use VB script (if I remember well it's the default for ArcMap ) your expression should work. Could you add a picture of your calculate field setting ?

Comment: Added picture of Field Calculator. the length of the field is 254. What is happening is staff are hand edit this string"urn:emergency:uid:gis:SSAP:507269:orangecountyfl.net" and changing the numbers. I'm just trying to make things easier with hand typed errors.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with your expression or setting. You may check for null value in your field but even if there are it shouldn't give you an error. As last resort try to restart your computer and try the calculation in a new mxd

Comment: Enclose the numeric fields in a `cstr()` such as `cstr([OBJECTID])`. Also replace + with &.

Comment: Can't you just add double quotes around each of the two fields? If OBJECTID is a number you're trying to concatenate a string with a number.

Comment: I used Hornbydd's comment worked like a charm.   I used this: "urn:emergency:uid:gis:SSAP:" & cstr([OBJECTID]) & ":" & [DISCRPAGID] this is the result:  urn:emergency:uid:gis:SSAP:508252:orangecountyfl.net